# How to change button image on tapped in repeating cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**I'm doing todolist app and I need action for button, which on tapped will do change image in a cell which I tapped on it. Cell retrieves data from Firebase to UITableView.** I used button and image outlets and both reported this error:

> The button from the TaskViewController to the UIButton is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

I have this code for retrieves data to cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TasksCell", for: indexPath) as! TasksCell

    let arrayTasks = tasks[indexPath.row]

    cell.taskName.text = arrayTasks.content

    return cell
}
```

and I have this in Storyboard

[image]

object left of the label is button.

The button picture is set in storyboard.

I don't know how to do it, because I don't have much experience. Please help me.

Comment: Looks alright to me... Where are you making the connection for the image? Make sure you're control-dragging from the image in the prototype cell to the code for the `TasksCell` class.

Comment: Displays the same mistake. I do this in TaskCell. But I do not know how to do the action when I tapped on button, which makes the action only on that cell where I tapped.

Comment: That message indicates you are trying to connect the action to the ViewController, not the cell. You can use a delegation pattern to get the event to the view controller

Comment: Okay, but I don't know how to use it. Can you help me please? I am a beginner.

Comment: Paulw11 is right (basically what I said). So are bubuxu and slysysl. See my answer for details on the steps required to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

1. Open the Identity Inspector.
2. Click the prototype cell.
3. Set the `Class` to `TasksCell` (in my example, it is `WorkTableViewCell`).
4. Click in the `Module` field, empty it, and press enter. It should change to `Current - project_name_here` (for example, `Current - Artistry`.

Here's a screenshot of what it should look like. Check it to make sure you selected the right items in the right order:

[image: instructions image]

Then, delete the old outlet(s) to the cell (button, label, everything) from the Connections Inspector. Do that step while selecting the cell, and then while selecting the view controller (but while selecting the view controller, *only* delete the outlet to the "completed" button).

[image: delete the old outlet(s)]

And finally, re-add them by opening the code (in a new window) for your **`TasksCell` class, *not* the `TaskViewController`** class (probably in `TasksCell.swift`), and *directly under the line*:

```
class TasksCell: UITableViewCell {
```

(or similar), hold **control** and drag the button, label, etc. as shown:

[image: create new outlets]

And finally, finish creating the new outlets **only from *the label, button, etc.* to *the TasksCell class* as mentioned earlier** (see note below before pressing "connect"):

[image: new outlets]

Change the `Name` as necessary. It could be something like `taskName` for the label, or `completedButton` for the button. Do not change the `Type` or any other fields. Press "connect", and the code from your question should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your TasksCell class, connect the button to the cell, and you can access it easier (yeah agree to @ingraham, you can't connect it to your view controller):

```
class TasksCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonCheckbox: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var taskName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var updatedDate: UILabel!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use image view for button. Also you can use this method for changing image

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelec tRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}
```

Edit:

I made a table view cell class:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBAction func bAction(_ sender: Any) {
         button.titleLabel?.text = "asdaf"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
     // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

then  I edit tableView function:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt    indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


       let cell: TableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
       cell.textLabel?.text = "abc"
    // Configure the cell...

       cell.bAction(Any.self)
       return cell
}
```

Comment: And change it when I tapped the button? I do not know, but I've only used this function in action handle on the whole cell. So how do I use only tapped on the button?